# How does 'airbreak' work on airsoft guns?

Tags: equipment, airsoft

I'm a rookie in the sport of Airsoft and have heard of *airbreak* feature installation but still couldn't figure out how it works.

It is known to be used for making the Airsoft gun more silent, but I couldn't understand exactly how.

Also it would be nice to know what are the cons as well when having it installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at this thread on the [Airsoft forum](http://www.airsoftforum.com/board/Air-Brake-Mod-t29967.html&p=16950563) and especially tmfreak's answer.

Basically the airbrake stops the piston smacking against the end of the cylinder.

It does reduce the speed of the projectile a little, and it isn't suitable for all airsoft guns, but worth looking at if the noise is an issue for you.

Answer (score 2):

The airframe works by creating a cushion of air between the piston head which is powered forward by the main  cylinder spring and the cylinder head.

This reduces the impact of the two surfaces hitting each other and producing the distinctive crack of an airsoft gun.

It will also reduce the speed (FPS) of the projectile due to using some of the air inside the cylinder to create the cushion.